# AzurePipeline Kubernetes must specify one of -f and -k

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I have an error message on the azure pipeline when performing deploy step on azure pipeline.
For my azure pipeline there is no changes, but there is changes on the deployment.yaml. 
The yaml, now accept 2 services and 2 deployment, the 2nd pic is the yaml content.
I would like to know what is wrong about this deploy, how to fixed it?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: add code instead of screenshot

Comment: please refer to the  3rd pic for the azure pipeline.yaml file

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Please refer to the 3rd image, I mark the red line. The code is to perform deployment.yaml. deployment.yaml is on the 2nd picture.

Comment: point me the doc you are referring to do this

Comment: Please don't post code (or error/exception messages, log files, configuration files, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image. Images are not indexable, harder to read and copy/paste. To read more about it please refer to [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could set variable `system.debug` to `true` to get detailed log, which may give you more inforamion.

Second, double check the location of deployment.yml, maybe it locates in `manifests/deployment.yml` or `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deployment.yml`, etc.

Useful documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/deploy?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/aks-template?view=azure-devops

Instead of using the KubernetesManifest task for deployment, one can also use the following alternatives to check the results:

- [Kubectl task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops)
- kubectl invocation on script. For example: `script: kubectl apply -f manifest.yml`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
First: It help me see the logs of the azure pipeline
Second: I check the manifest is correct but is not able to work, I'm using the alternative kubectl task and change the deployment.yml for the imagepull is work :)

Answer (score -2):

The -f option requires an argument, the path of the file to apply.

Example:

```
kubectl apply -f filename.yaml --namespace default
```